# Using Masonry, focus changes when a new item is added to the grid, forcing scroll

Tags: javascript, grid, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using Masonry JS from https://masonry.desandro.com/
My issue is that the focus changes as soon as a new item is added.
In my code, new items are appended at the beginning of the grid.
But, if I'm looking at an item that made me scroll down several times, so the first items are not visible now, as soon as a new item is added, the page automatically scrolls up to the top of the grid, not letting me keep looking where I was.
This is very annoying.
Any idea?
Thanks.